# How to control browser tab change jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, tabs, window

I have some JavaScript to control browser window change, if the user change the tab or window a JavaScript countdown is reseted.

But in my content have a iframe then need be accessed and the countdown can't be reseted during the access.

If the user click on the iframe content the countdown is reseted, but its not can happen.
How can I control this?

Above my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var isActive;
    var g_timer = null;
    var numero = 90;

    window.onfocus = function () { 
    isActive = true; 
    }; 

    window.onblur = function () { 
    isActive = false; 
    }; 

    setInterval(function () { 
    window.isActive ? decCount() : resetCount(); 
    }, 1000);

    function decCount(){
      if(numero > 0){
          document.getElementById('timers').innerHTML = --numero;
      }
    }

    function resetCount(){
      numero = 91;
      clearTimeout(g_timer);
      startTimer();
    }

    function startTimer() {
      g_timer = window.setTimeout(function() {
          window.location.href = '/office/tasks/secure/';
      }, 92000);
    }

    function timersfocus(){
      $('#timers').focus();
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `blur()` event from jquery

```
$(window).blur(function() {
    //your code here when window/tab changes
});
```